# continuous one- one function from $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Is there exist a continuous one- one function from $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$?

## My attempt : Yes

Yes, there exists such a function.

Biject $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ to get $\mathbb{Q} = \{q_n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, and let $\mathbb{L}$ be the set of irrational numbers.

Define $L_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{L} \cap (n, n+1)$. Then define $f(x) = q_n$ for all $x \in \mathbb{L_n}$.

It will give one one  continuous function because  any irrational number in $\mathbb{L_n}$, there is a small neighbourhood of it which is contained entirely within $\mathbb{L}_n$

Is its true ?

Comment: yes @Darman but what u want to say

Comment: $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ is uncountable, $\mathbb Q$ is countable. So **No**?

Comment: see my mapping @QuangHoang

Comment: You should check the definition of a one-one function - your function is continuous, but it's *really* not one-one.

Comment: How are you enumerating $\mathbb{Q}$? It doesnt make sense to claim that $f$ is continuous as stated (and in fact you havent defined an injective function because you send infinitely many irrationals to each $q_n$). Also you cannot have such a function because no function between those sets will be bijective.

Comment: Like commented, your function is neither continuous nor one-one. You should **really** consider my other comment.

Comment: @MiloBrandt  my function is one one ....its  satisfied $x_1 \neq x_2$  implies $f(x_1) \ne  f(x_2)$

Comment: @jasmine no it's not, how $f(x) = q_n$ for all $x\in L_n$ is one-one?

Comment: If $x\in L_1 $ $f(x)=q_1$, So isn't 1-1

Comment: @QuangHoang the  endpoints of  $L_n$  are rational  so it is continious  and one one

Comment: That doesnt imply either of those things.

Comment: You should really review the other comments.For example, $f(\sqrt{2})$ and $f(\sqrt{2}+0.1))$ are equal. So $f$ is not one-one. This is my last comment. I'm sorry but I don't see the point to discuss further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is not injective because $f(x)=f(y)$ for any distinct $x,y\in \mathbb{L}_n$.

Indeed if there would exists an injective function $f:\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q \to \Bbb Q $ then the cardinality of $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q $ would be less or equal to the cardinality of $\Bbb Q $, however we already knows that this is not true.